# Why is appengine scaling so many idle instances?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

This is a view of the past week for my java google appengine application:

[image]

As you can see, the number of active instances is never actually above 1, but Google have scaled up over 40 idle instances during a spike that lasted over 24 hours. This has caused quota exceeded errors. (Over $75 in one day for a low traffic app!)

My config was like this:

```
<automatic-scaling>
    <min-idle-instances>1</min-idle-instances>
    <max-idle-instances>automatic</max-idle-instances>
</automatic-scaling>
```

I have now set the `max-idle-instances` to 2 instances to see if that solves it. However, I don't feel happy not understanding why so many were scaled up in the first place. There doesn't appear to have been any unusual traffic to cause such a surge. This isn't the first time this has happened. Any ideas?

Comment: why are you not asking google about this instead?

Comment: can you check how many incoming requests were coming during that spike?

Comment: @TimCastelijns because this is normally faster and official support isn't free (despite me paying them quite a lot in hosting fees)

Comment: @MichaelMeyer there was nothing unusual about the volume of requests. The graphs don't correlate.

Comment: @mattburns How you get that chart?. Stackdriver?

Comment: @Ale you can see a chart of instances on app engine dashboard. Go to the Instances menu, then also pick instances from the dropdown. Or visit https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/instances?project=oddprints&graph=AE_INSTANCES but replace `oddprints` with your app id.

Comment: Actually, it looks like I used Stackdriver. Visit resources > appengine > then click `system` tab.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your configuration:

```
<max-idle-instances>automatic</max-idle-instances>
```

It should be

```
<max-idle-instances>1</max-idle-instances>
```

It means that google will always keep at least one instance without any traffic. It will be used when serving instances are overloaded and it allows the load-balancer to kick new instances.

Official documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#scaling_elements)

If you wish to be ready for high traffic spikes, it is possible to adjust the min-idle-instances instead. Otherwise, max-idle-instances set 1 is enough in most cases.